# How do I continue my python 3.4 installation in anaconda after a connection error?

Tags: python, cmd, python-3.4, anaconda

I have been trying to update the python version in Anaconda 2.1.0 from python 2.7.8 to python 3.4

I used

```
conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda
```

It was downloading the modules required and I think it had downloaded till pytest when it showed an error (path does not exist) and then showed a connection error.

I have been trying to continue the installation . 
However , whenever I try the above command it shows:-

```
Error: prefix already exists: C:\Users\SCHOOL\Anaconda\envs\py3k
```

How do I continue my installation?
Is there any specific options that I can use with the command to continue it?
I tried going through the options available but it was very confusing.

I have tried activating py3k inorder to see the modules installed.

```
activate py3k 
('modules')
```

However, it is of no help

Comment: does `conda remove --all --name py3k` followed by `conda create -n py3k python=3.5 anaconda` work?

Comment: I don't want to delete what has been installed . I just want to continue from where I lost connection. Is there a way?